# Objective-C: Button's border colour is not getting displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

I am trying to get the border on a button working for quite some time.

```
[self.accountButton.layer setBorderColor:(__bridge CGColorRef _Nullable)UIColorFromRGB( kGABrandingGreenColor )];
```

This is how the color's value is generated.

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) ([UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
                                              green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
                                               blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 \
                                              alpha:1.0])

#define kGABrandingGreenColor       (0x53C2BE)
```

I haven't found a solution in stackoverflow which solves my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's easy

```
    #define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) \
[UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
green:((float)((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >>  8))/255.0 \
blue:((float)((rgbValue & 0x0000FF) >>  0))/255.0 \
alpha:1.0]

#define kGABrandingGreenColor       (0xBC1128)


[self.accountButton.layer setBorderWidth:3.0];
[self.accountButton.layer setBorderColor:[UIColorFromRGB(kGABrandingGreenColor) CGColor]];
```

Comment: Thanks a ton mate!

Answer (score 0):

You're close, just add the .CGColor to the define and remove the bridge. Also you need to set a borderWidth otherwise you won't see anything

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) ([UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
                                          green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
                                           blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 \
                                          alpha:1.0]).CGColor

#define kGABrandingGreenColor       (0x53C2BE)


[self.accountButton.layer setBorderColor:UIColorFromRGB( kGABrandingGreenColor)];
self.accountButton.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
```